# get meta value from database by post id

Tags: plugins, post-meta

I am just really confused how to do this, becouse I am newbie in wordpress. So what am trying to do:

I have a custom form on home page and posting form value by post method. Now I want to fetch meta value by the comparision of post value.

I am trying

```
<?php 
$from=$_POST['a'];
$to=$_POST['b'];
$froms = get_post_meta( 139, 'from',true );
print_r($froms);
$tos = get_post_meta( 139, 'to',true ); 
if($froms=$from && $to=$tos) 
{
echo "test match";
}
else
{
echo "Not found";
}
```

Now for whatever value of $from its showing match found.

and if i tried to `print_r($from)` it always show `Array([0]=>"test")`

feel free to ask me if my question is unclear, how can i fetch meta value by some comparision of posted value..

**I just want to check if my meta value and posted form value are same then `echo "test match"`, if my posted value did not match with meta value then `echo "not found"`**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the third parameter of the `get_post_meta()`.
If the third parameter is set to **true** then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields

for example:--

```
$froms = get_post_meta( 139, 'from', true );
$tos = get_post_meta( 139, 'to', true );
```

For more details look into the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Parameters)

Comment: Thanks Mohanty, for valuable knowledge now i am getting meta value without array, but why it is always showing "test match" while I am changing the form posting value....

Comment: I cannot tell that until unless I look more into the code, I can see you are checking the values and if true echoing **test match**.

Comment: yes, and it always going true...

Comment: can you tell me what are you trying to accomplish and what do you think is going wrong here?

Comment: sir see my update, i just want to check meta value if they are same as posted value should perform some specific action.....

Comment: use '==' to check the values '===' to match the type too and not '=', the above '=' is setting the value which is always true

Comment: Glad it helped you :)